# For what relative growth rate of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ will $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \rightarrow 0$, and $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} f(x) \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

For some relative growth rate of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$,

$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \rightarrow 0$

What relative growth rate? Less than half?

Similarly, for what relative growth rate will it be true that:

$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} f(x) \rightarrow 0$

? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We havae $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 0$ as long as $f(x)$ is small compared with $g(x)$. For instance, $f(x) = 1/x^2, g(x) = 1/x$, or $f(x) = \sqrt{x}, g(x)=x$, or $f(x) = x^2, g(x) = x^3$ both would do.

The other one is similar. Hint: in the two examples above, which one satisfies $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}f(x) \to 0$?

Comment: Thanks so much Wang Yuxin. So, if (f(x))^2<g(x), then (f(x)/g(x))*f(x) ->0 ?  Great - can you show me how to prove this?

Comment: "if $(f(x))^2<g(x)$, then $(f(x)/g(x))\cdot f(x) \to 0$" is incorrect: consider $f(x) = \sqrt{x}, g(x) = 2x$. They have to differ in order. In practice, one easy way to justify such limits is to use L'Hopital's rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: hmm, l'hopital's rule goes way beyond my competence unfortunately. You said that the first rule was satisfied as long as f(x) is 'small compared with g(x)' - but exactly how small, and how did you figure that out? Is there any straightforward way to decide what the conditions are for the function to approach zero? (or what those conditions in fact are?) Thanks again.

Comment: One intuitive way is to check the order. $x^n$ is "smaller" when $n$ is smaller; $1/x^n$ is "smaller" when $n$ is larger; $\ln(x)$ is "smaller" than any $x^n$ for $n > 0$; $e^x$ is "larger" than any $x^n$, etc.

Comment: Thank you Yuxin!